# Call from the service to the c# controller 404 error

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call a method in c# controller from my service and I am getting 404 error. The getTopics method is in AdminController.cs. I added the getTopics code as well. If I change the path I am getting 401 (Unauthorized).Does it mean that my path is right but I am not authorized to access it?

```
var adminService = function () {
    this.baseUrl = $location.protocol() + "://" + location.host + "/";
}



adminService.prototype.getTopics = function () {
    var self = this;


    var promise = $http(
    {
        method: 'POST',
        url: self.baseUrl + 'Admin/getTopics',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: That screenshot of a folder structure doesn't provide any context to help answer this question.  Showing the *contents* of that file might be another matter, but since this is a 404 error, how the server is configured (the MVC or WebAPI router) is the info that is needed here.

Comment: Does the getTopics  is HTTPGet or HTTP Post, it seems you calling a get method with 'POST' call

Comment: I added getTopics as well

Comment: So, you're asking if an error message saying "Unauthorized" means that you're not authorized?

Comment: But this is a folder in my vs and I never have this problem before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this MVC? if so you could dummy up what it should be by setting a variable in your cshtml file around some script tags.

```
<script>
 var getTopicsLink = '@Url.Action("getTopics", "Admin")';
</script>
```

Comment: No it is mvc with angular and I can not access the link with that.

Comment: you dont have access to the view?

Comment: I meant I can not access it

Comment: Do you have an action that you know works? Is it just that one? You could verify the path using the Request.Url.AbsoluteUri variable

Comment: Just this one. If I change the path I am getting 401 (Unauthorized).Does it mean that my path is right but I am not authorized to access it?

Comment: Yes. Thats what it sounds like. Do you have access to the server? i would verify your permissions. If this is the first action in that controller, that makes sense